# W3 total cache and cloudflare wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

I am just a little confused using these two things together.

I am using W3 total cache on my blog alone with cloudflare. Now I know W3 total cache integrates cloudflare pretty well. I entered my API and stuff. But I noticed W3 total cache has a place for CDN credentials.

Do I need to do anything here, since I Want to use cloudflare as my CDN? Should I just disable CDN within w3 total cache?

Also is it better to minify css,js, etc with cloudflare or w3? or both?

Answer (score 0):

We cover [W3TC and CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169546-What-fields-do-I-need-to-enter-in-W3TC-W3-Total-Cache-settings-) in our knowledge base.

Do I need to do anything here, since I Want to use cloudflare as my CDN? Should I just disable CDN within w3 total cache? This doesn't apply to CloudFlare and there is nothing to configure there relative to us (that's for if you're using a traditional CDN provider that requires a subdomain). CloudFlare's caching [works via file extensions](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) and not through a subdomain of some sort.

"Do I need to do anything here, since I Want to use cloudflare as my CDN? Should I just disable CDN within w3 total cache? "

Comment: The first link is dead.